What did early Indo-Europeans wear? What are some PIE words related to clothing? I know only *wļneh2 (wool) and *lino (flax)
So, I am interested, what did the Proto-Indo-Europeans wear? I happen to know only two PIE words related to clothing: *wļneh2 (wool) and *lino (flax). And I know that some linguists doubt that the word *lino really existed in PIE, primarily because of the lack of cognates in Indo-Iranian (Why would the word for flax get lost when they clearly grew flax in their new homeland?).

Loss of a word is not a strong counterargument, words get replaced in languages more or less arbitrarily, and a substrate, superstrate or adstrate word may win over the inherited one. Also, the full process of cultivating flax and getting at linen is complex and may get lost, e.g., in a nomadic culture.

Although Late Proto-Indoeuropeans may have known wool Early PIE (Indo-Anatolians) didn't. Woolly sheep (as opposed to hairy sheep) only appeared after 3,600 BC whereas the Anatolian split with the other Indo-Europeans happened before 4000 BC. See
Kloekhorst, Alwin "Wool and the Indo Anatolian Hypothesis" (Presentation) (Uppsala: 2023)
Available from Author on Academia.edu at https://www.academia.edu/123968955/Wool_and_the_Indo_Anatolian_Hypothesis (Accessed: 19/9/2024)

Mallory and Adams' Oxford Introduction to Proto-Indo-European and the Proto-Indo-European World has a chapter on clothing and textiles.
They don't really reconstruct words for any specific type of garment, but they've got *wospo/ehₐ- 'garment' (Mallory and Adams spuriously reconstruct a second a-colouring laryngeal *h₄, so when it's not clear to them whether a given laryngeal is *h₂ or *h₄ they tend to write it as *hₐ) and *drap- ~ *drop- 'clothes, cloak'.
*wospo/ehₐ- they claim has reflexes in Anatolian in Hittite was(sa)pa- 'garment, shroud', Luwian waspant- 'wearing funeral shrouds', and in Latin vespa 'one who steals clothes from the dead' (which is a fairly outrageous gloss on their part). It's pretty transparently derived from *wes- 'be dressed', which has secure reflexes in e.g. Greek ἕννυμι 'clothe' and nominal derivations like Latin vestis 'garment'.
*drap- ~ *drop- they reconstruct based on Latin-loan-from-Gaulish drappus 'clothes' (actually '(piece of) cloth'), Lithuanian drãpanos 'clothes', Sanskrit drāpi- 'cloak'. They mention *drep- 'split off' as a potential source, so that it may originally have referred to a skin garment. (Elsewhere they gloss *drep- as 'scratch, tear'.)
They also list quite a few roots and stems related or possibly related to cloth production: *pek̑- 'pluck out [wool]', *reu(H)- 'id.', *kars- 'scratch; comb (wool)', *kes- 'comb', *nak- 'press, squeeze', *plek̑- 'braid, plait', *resg- 'plait, wattle', *wei(h₁)- 'id.', *kert- 'plait, twine', *(s)neh₁(i)- 'twist fibres into thread', *sneh₁u- 'id.', *(s)pen- 'draw, spin', *terk(w)- 'twist < spin', *h₂/h₃eu 'weave', *h₂/h₃webʰ- 'id.', *weg- 'plait, weave', *melk- 'plait, spin', *syuh₁- 'sew', *(s)ner- 'fasten with thread or cord', *ned- 'knot'.
A number of these are very questionable, but taken together they do paint a picture of a society that knew how to weave cloth and seems to have done it from plucked wool at least some of the time. (Shearable sheep were a relatively late development; initially wool was produced by plucking hair from goats and sheep when they moulted, and shearing didn't become feasible until we bred sheep with longer hair around ~6000 BCE. Plucking, or "rooing", is still how a number of fancier wools are produced today.)
E.J.W. Barber's Prehistoric Textiles observes with rather more care and nuance that Greek has a double vocabulary related to cloth production, with a layer of inherited Indo-European terms and at least two additional layers that were borrowed later, and makes the case that the Proto-Indo-European world knew band looms but that warp-weighted looms were a later innovation. Shed bars, heddles, and heddle bars came later still.
She also looks at depictions of clothing in art that has survived to try to reconstruct how e.g. specific Mycenaean clothes were produced. Obviously this is centuries to millennia after Proto-Indo-European times and it's both a lot more technical and more subtle than "they wore this type of chiton" (χιτών is a Phoenician loanword anyway), but it's as close as you're likely to get and well worth anyone's time. Her later work, reflected in The Mummies of Ürümchi, also looks at the textiles of the Tarim mummies.
